# Create Table in Google Docs with App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

I am trying to create a table in a google docs, from a table in App Maker. So far I have:

```
function updateDoco() {  
var check = {};  
var projectItemQuery = app.models.ProjectItem.newQuery();
var values = projectItemQuery.run(); 
    values.forEach(function(item){
    if(!check.hasOwnProperty(item.Project)){
      check[item.Project] = true; 
var docId = agResponse.id;                 
var activityGuide = DocumentApp.openById(docId);
var actvityGuideBody = activityGuide.getBody();                  
for (var i = 0; i<values.length; i++) {
var name = values[i].Name;  
var docTitle = actvityGuideBody.insertParagraph(i, name); 
    docTitle.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1); 
}
var steps = app.models.Steps.newQuery();
var activity = steps.run();      
    activity.forEach(function(steps){
     if(!check.hasOwnProperty(steps.Function)){
         check[steps.Functions] = true; 
var table = actvityGuideBody.appendTable();
  for(var n=0; n<activity; n++){
    var step = activity[n].Step;
    var data = [n, step, ''];
    var tr = table.appendTableRow(data);
     }      
   }     
 });

doc.saveAndClose();
```

How do I get the results from the query into the table in a google doc?

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: I'm guessing this is a server script? If that is the case, just a heads up, but it would appear that your functionsQuery won't return anything as you never actually run that query. It would also help to post a more complete code example in regards to what you have tried to write the data to your google doc.

Comment: Yes, it's a server script. You're right, I forgot the run step. I think I'm getting a bit confused though because I'm running a query on a query. The "steps" are a relation to the ProjectItem table. I want column one to get the steps based on the function. I updated the OP with more complete code.

Comment: So your rowsData functionsQuery[1] specifically points to the second record of the functions query. If your functionsQuery only returns 1 record, then functionsQuery[1] will be a null or undefined value. Furthermore, even if you use functionsQuery[0] this still points to an entire record, so if you want a string returned instead you will need to construct this string using functionsQuery[0].MyField1 + ' ' + functionsQuery[0].MyField2 etc. However I'm not certain if that is what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I actually want to create a loop which creates a table with all the records in a related table based on the function in each line. so if there are 10 lines, I would end up with 10 tables, and each table would have the corresponding rows from the related table.I was trying to start small and work up to the loops, but can't even get one result, let alone a loop yet.

Comment: Ok, I see where you are going now. The thing that threw me off was the ‘goat’, ‘basil’, ‘cat’ stuff in your rows data array. Last clarifying question, is your model relation ProjectItem to Function (one to many) and do you want all 10 tables (per your example) in the same document? Just on a side note, you are able to prefetch any relations data in your ProjectItemQuery, so you don’t actually ever have to run the second query.

Comment: Yeah the goat, basil stuff was a sample to see if I could get it creating, and I'd planned to work up from there. The relation is actually a many to many relationship. The functions will be used in a lot of different projects. I would like them in the same document, so it ends up being one big document with all the functions, and the steps for each.

Comment: I do have a script which did what I wanted from a google sheet which I was building up to once I can figure out how it works with app maker tables. I can share that if you think it would help?

Comment: I have updated the code based on where I am now. I think I'm closer because I can now get a result for other documents. I just need to get it to populate the table properly now.

Comment: At the moment when I paste your code into App Maker it gives me unmatched {} errors. Also, your new code now runs two loops on your projectItemQuery results, is that supposed to be that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is my best attempt at a solution for you. I would certainly suggest prefetching your ProjectItem steps instead of running a separate query in the for loop. However from there with your code edits it was somewhat lost if you wanted many tables in the same document or otherwise. However here is a potential code solution for you:

```
function updateDoco() {
  var check = {};  
  var projectItemQuery = app.models.ProjectItem.newQuery();
  projectItemQuery.prefetch.Function._add(); //prefetch for project item to 
    function relation (many-to-many)
  projectItemQuery.prefetch.Function.Steps._add();  //prefetch for function 
    to steps relation (one-to-many)
  var values = projectItemQuery.run();

  for (var i in values) {
    if(!check.hasOwnProperty(values[i].Project)) {
      check[values[i].Project] = true;
    }
    var docId = agResponse.id;                 
    var activityGuide = DocumentApp.openById(docId);
    var activityGuideBody = activityGuide.getBody();

    var name = values[i].Name;  
    var docTitle = activityGuideBody.insertParagraph(i, name);
    docTitle.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);

    var functions = values[i].Function;

    //loop to run through each function relation on your current ProjectItem
    for (var j in functions) {
      var rowsdata = [['Step','Description']];
      var steps = functions[j].Steps;
      //another loop to run through each step to function relation
      for (var k in steps) {
        rowsdata.push([steps[k].Step,steps[k].Description]);
      }
      activityGuideBody.appendTable(rowsdata);
    }
    doc.saveAndClose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So yes, I wanted multiple tables. I wasn't sure how to update you on my progress without changing the original post. I tried putting it in a comment and it was too many characters. Is there a better way? A couple of questions. your comment "  this should be your ProjectItem many-to- ". Do I need to put another var in there for the related table? When I ran it, I got the message " Cannot call method "_add" of undefined. at updateDoco". Thanks again for all your help. I'm continuing to work on it too and think we're getting close!

Comment: In my script I am trying to prefetch your Steps?/Function? relation instead of calling a separate query on it. I think prefetching your relation data instead of calling a separate query is going to make the script more efficient. This is where I wasn't sure what your relation end was called, but you did mention that your Project item had a many-to-many relation to the data you wanted in the tables.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll work on it now and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: I'm getting a little bit stuck. So when I run the query on the "parent" table, I am able to get a list of the fields to choose from, but not the related fields. If I run it on the related table, I get the correct fields to pick, but no results. I think I'm missing something?

Comment: Which one is your parent table? ProjectItem or Steps? Looking at your latest code in your question you have model ProjectItem and Steps. When you check your Steps model against the presence of steps.Function is the 'Function' your relation end to ProjectItem? I think the portion we keep getting hung up on is your relation end between ProjectItem and Steps. If you could somehow provide me an example of your fields for each model and the relations between each model I will create some mirror models in my application and then run some tests.

Comment: Yes, projectItem is the parent. So the function might be called "Login to system", and the steps are "Enter Username", "Enter Password", "Click the submit button". I think what's tripping it up is that the function is actually another related table which has nothing but the function names. I did it this way so I could pick multiple functions for each projectItem with a multiselect box (hence the many to many relationship. Then the steps for each function is in another table which is a one to many relationship. It simply has the step, and the relation.

Comment: @Kat Taking the additional relation into consideration, I have revised my code in my answer. Basically with that additional relation you will need to introduce another nested loop for a total of 3 loops. You may still need to change some variable or relation names around to fit your setup though.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I think I'm getting it now. For related records you need to loop the records which makes sense. Two tables with relations means two loops. I think what was throwing me was I could use prefetch to get all the records I needed from the initial query. I will try it now.

Comment: Your solution worked. Thank you so much for your help! I still have a bit of tweaking to do to get the formatting looking like I want, but I get it now :)